# Android Viewholder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

```
package com.jakewalther.x;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<users> users;
public adapter(List<users> getDataAdapter, Context context){
    super();
    this.users = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

public adapter(List<users> usersList, LoadXOrgasm context) {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    users getDataAdapter1 =  users.get(position);
    holder.UserName.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView UserName;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        UserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewCard) ;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make an adapter for a recycler view. **Getting a compile error cannot find UserName at the line**

```
holder.UserName.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());
```

I have tried everything I can't figure out why the code won't run.

Comment: welcome. please read about how to ask a good question that is likely to get a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post your xml for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is You are extending ViewHolder of `RecylerView`, not your custom ViewHolder.in `onBindViewMethod()` you have to check that holder instance will be of Your custom `Viewholder` instance.

```
 if(holder intanceOf ViewHolder ){ //here ViewHolder is your custom holder class 

            ((ViewHolder ) holder).UserName((getDataAdapter1.getName());

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

replace your onBindViewHolder with this,

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
        users getDataAdapter1 =  users.get(position);
        viewHolder.UserName.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());
    }
```